# How to trigger onNavigationItemSelected() programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a *navigation drawer* with 3 menu items. In my `MainActivity.java`, I set `onNavigationItemSelected()` listener to handle navigation items clicked. When clicked, a *custom drawer dialog* is shown.

*Navigation drawer*

[image: Navigation drawer]

*Custom drawer dialog (Tiled Layers)*

[image: Custom drawer dialog (Tiled Layers)]

*MainActivity.java*

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Create custom drawer dialog
    drawerDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    drawerDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_drawer);

    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int selectedItemId = item.getItemId();
    if (selectedItemId == R.id.layerMenu)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (selectedItemId == R.id.basemapMenu)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (selectedItemId == R.id.tiledLayerMenu)
    {
        // Setup drawer dialog (Tiled Layers)        
    }

    // Show drawer dialog
    drawerDialog.show();

    ...
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

I also have a *custom notice dialog*. When No Data Found notice dialog appear, I have **Download button that will open drawer dialog (Tiled Layers).**

*Custom notice dialog (No Data Found)*

[image: Custom notice dialog (No Data Found)]

Now.. **how do I trigger `onNavigationItemSelected()` programmatically** on Download button click? This is what I have tried but not successful:

```
    downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // Trying to click Tiled Layers navigation item here                
            // 1
            //NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.mainNavView);
            //navigationView.getMenu().getChildAt(2).performClick();            
            // 2
            //((NavigationMenuItemView) findViewById(R.id.tiledLayerMenu)).callOnClick();            
            // 3
            //onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(2))); //

            // Close dialog
            noticeDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Please help me. Thank you.

---

## UPDATE

Ok..I just simply do something like LQ Gioan suggest and it works. I moved all the long codes in `onNavigationItemSelected()` to new function `showDrawerDialog` and pass item id. In button click, I also do the same. No need to find out the `MenuItem`, only pass the item id. Thanks!

*MainActivity.java*

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int selectedItemId = item.getItemId();
    showDrawerDialog(selectedItemId);

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void showDrawerDialog(final int selectedItemId)
{        
    // Create custom drawer dialog
    drawerDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    drawerDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_drawer);

    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    //int selectedItemId = item.getItemId();
    if (selectedItemId == R.id.layerMenu)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (selectedItemId == R.id.tiledLayerMenu)
    {
        // Setup drawer dialog (Tiled Layers)        
    }

    // Show drawer dialog
    drawerDialog.show();
}
```

On download button click,

```
    downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // Trying to click Tiled Layers navigation item here                
            showDialogDrawer(R.id.tiledLayerMenu);

            // Close dialog
            noticeDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you call a method that  will show the "Tiled Layers" dialog directly ?

Comment: I cannot do so..bcs my real code in 'onNavigationItemSelected()` is more complicated than I write above. Based on `selectedItemId`, I set up different function and UI visibility that related, all need to be inside 'onNavigationItemSelected()`

Comment: Instead of opening download data and in background and on completion just show a toast saying download successful

Comment: @LQGioan ok..i tried something like u suggest and it worked. haha i feel so $^*&&. Thank you

Comment: @Anonymous i need to open the download dialog. In this app user have download preference (by section/etc) before download

Answer (score 1):

### You can use this tricks

Little change `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

First of all declare a int class variable

```
//clicked id holder
int clicked = 0;
```

Now use it in `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

  int selectedItemId = item.getItemId();
  if (selectedItemId == R.id.layerMenu || clicked == R.id.layerMenu)
  {
    //your  action code
  }
  else if (selectedItemId == R.id.tiledLayerMenu || clicked == R.id.tiledLayerMenu)
  {
    // your  action code       
  }
  //clear clicked value
  clicked = 0;

  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
  return true;
}
```

Edit in your button clicked

```
downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        //setting id to clicked variable 
        clicked  = R.id.m_layerMenu;
        //fire the  navigation selection
       onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));
    }
});
```

I do it and test it for you ... it works 100%... try it .. good luck.

Comment: Yes! I tested and it works..but it will take from this line `onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));`. Dont know why it didnt work earlier..hhu. And the clicked variable is good idea also, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> > Its very easy, One Line Answer !

```
onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.my_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method on any menu in android.

```
yourMenu.performIdentifierAction(menuItemId, flags)
```

Depending on the flag, you can choose whether to close the menu host or not.